# Strange Python memory allocation

Tags: python, numpy, memory-profiling

While trying to figure out how Python's garbage collection system works, I stumbled across this oddity. Running this simple code:

```
import numpy as np
from memory_profiler import profile

@profile
def my_func():
    a = np.random.rand(1000000)
    a = np.append(a, [1])
    a = np.append(a, [2])
    a = np.append(a, [3])
    a = np.append(a, [4])
    a = np.append(a, [5])
    b = np.append(a, [6])
    c = np.append(a, [7])
    d = np.append(a, a)

    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_func()
```

using memory_profiler version 0.52 and Python 3.7.6 on my MacBook, I got the following output:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     4     54.2 MiB     54.2 MiB   @profile
     5                             def my_func():
     6     61.8 MiB      7.7 MiB       a = np.random.rand(1000000)
     7     69.4 MiB      7.6 MiB       a = np.append(a, [1])
     8     69.4 MiB      0.0 MiB       a = np.append(a, [2])
     9     69.4 MiB      0.0 MiB       a = np.append(a, [3])
    10     69.4 MiB      0.0 MiB       a = np.append(a, [4])
    11     69.4 MiB      0.0 MiB       a = np.append(a, [5])
    12     69.4 MiB      0.0 MiB       b = np.append(a, [6])
    13     77.1 MiB      7.6 MiB       c = np.append(a, [7])
    14     92.3 MiB     15.3 MiB       d = np.append(a, a)
    15                             
    16     92.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       return a
```

Two things are odd. First, why is line 7 giving any more noticeable increase in memory than lines 8-11? Second, why isn't line 12 giving the same increase in memory as line 13?

Note that if I delete lines 12-14, I still get the increase in memory in line 7. So it's not a bug where the memory is actually being increased in line 12 but memory_profiler is incorrectly showing that increase in line 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creating `a` makes an array with 8e6 bytes  (check `a.nybtes)

```
 6     61.8 MiB      7.7 MiB       a = np.random.rand(1000000)
```

`np.append` makes a new array (it is `concatenate`, not list append), so we get another 8MB increase.

```
 7     69.4 MiB      7.6 MiB       a = np.append(a, [1])
```

my guess is that in following steps it cycles back and forth using those two 8MB blocks.  `numpy` doesn't return (to the OS) every free block.

Then you assign the new array to `c`.  `a` still exists, along with `b`.  (I missed `b` the first time I looked at this.)

```
13     77.1 MiB      7.6 MiB       c = np.append(a, [7])
```

`d` is twice the size of `a`, so that accounts for the 15MB jump.  `a,b,c` still exist.

```
14     92.3 MiB     15.3 MiB       d = np.append(a, a)
```

`b` and `c` are just one or two numbers bigger than `a` - so each takes up about 8MB.  That seems to account for everything!

When tracking memory use, keep in mind that `numpy`, `python` and the `OS` all play role.  Most of us don't know all the details, so we can only make rough guesses as to what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

In the line 7 could this be some form of overhead from profiler? From what I can see using `sys.getsizeof()` the array is incremented by 8 bytes at each append with no sudden jumps.

At first I thought that this could be a similar situation as with Python lists, where memory gets allocated once every 4 appends in 32-byte chunks, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Without a function or profiler I can see no behaviour similar to what you showed in your post. The only oddity I can see is that `d` is not exactly double the size of `a`.

```py
import numpy as np
import sys

a = np.random.rand(1000000)

sys.getsizeof(a)
Out[55]: 8000096

a = np.append(a, [1])

sys.getsizeof(a)
Out[57]: 8000104

a = np.append(a, [2])

sys.getsizeof(a)
Out[59]: 8000112

a = np.append(a, [3])

sys.getsizeof(a)
Out[61]: 8000120

a = np.append(a, [4])

sys.getsizeof(a)
Out[63]: 8000128

a = np.append(a, [5])

sys.getsizeof(a)
Out[66]: 8000136

a = np.append(a, [6])

sys.getsizeof(a)
Out[68]: 8000144

a = np.append(a, [7])

sys.getsizeof(a)
Out[71]: 8000152

d = np.append(a, a)

sys.getsizeof(d)
Out[73]: 16000208
```